# Django ManyToMany Field Querying

Tags: django, python-3.x

For days now i have been looking for the simplest way to go about solving  this problem . So i have  models ,user , Company Model , And product Model as bellow .

model .py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(models.Model)
    user=models.ForeignKey(user,unique=True,null=True,related_name="user")
    follow=models.ManyToMany(user,related_name="follow",null=True)

class Product(models.Model):
     name=models.Charfield(models.Model)
     company=models.ForeignKey(Company,related_name="Product",null=True)
```

In my view

```
def Display(request):
    #get all products 
     products=Product.objects.all()
     #get all company objects
     companies=Company.objects.all()
```

So the idea is users can follow companies and companies can post products . Assuming  userA is following companyA(usA has been added to ManyToManyField in Company), When companyA post a product, the product is displayed in usA timeline. I have done research and i even came across an app called django activity streaming . It was  complicated for me to integrate in to my project . Since i am just looking for something simple .I am reading django contenttype which tracks all models, but yet i have no idea how to implement it to solve my problem . Please if you have an idea on how i can solve this problem using django query set or any suggestion . I will gladly appreciate .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a user object. You can use the `related_name` [mod](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to access the reverse relation and by that get all companies that that user follows, after that we can get all products based on that companies:

```
companies user.follow.all()
products = Product.objects.filter(company__in=companies)
```

The `products` will have a list of all products that belongs to one of that user companies, if you are having problem if duplicate products, you can use the `distinct()` queryset method to fix it.